# How to compare exact list elements in 2 same length list?

Tags: python, list

Trying to compare the similarity of 2 lists, to see how many times the 2 lists match.

My code is this:

```
list1 = [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]
list2 = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]

def listCompare(lst1, lst2):
    for i in lst1:
        for j in lst2:
            if i == j:
                return i

print(listCompare(L1, M1))
```

This should return `2`, because only the first and second item (index `0` and `1`) are equal in both lists.

Comment: But you `return` an element of `lst1` (`i`)...

Comment: `sum(a==b for a,b in zip(list1,list2))`

Comment: Don't you want to only count if the *i*th elements in each list are equal? The way you've coded this up, it looks like you're trying to compare each element in `lst1` with *each element* in `lst2`. So, for `list1[0]`, there are technically four elements in `list2` that match `list1[0]` according to your current criterion. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this,

```
list1 = [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]
list2 = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]

n = sum(i==j for i, j in zip(list1, list2))

print(n)
# 2
```

Comment: @MSeifert, I prefer `operator` as well. Anyway, I've just upvoted ur answer.

Comment: You already proposed a good and solid solution with `zip` so there was actually no need to duplicate a solution. I didn't want to be rude but there were a few minutes between my answer and your update (and that would make my answer totally obsolete, especially after your answer was accepted). :)

Comment: @MSeifert, yup, SO did remind me there are new answers, but I didn't check it and just posted my edit. Next time, I will carefully check it to make sure my edit is not duplicated with others or reverse to the previous answer once duplicates exist.

Answer (score 3):

You could map `operator.eq` on both lists and then `sum` them:

```
>>> import operator
>>> sum(map(operator.eq, list1, list2))
2
```

You compared the cartesian-product (each item of `list1` with each item of `list2`) not the element-wise equality.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

```
list1 = [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]
list2 = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]

def listCompare(lst1, lst2):
    matches = 0
    for i in range(0, len(lst1)):
        if lst1[i] == lst2[i]:
            matches += 1
    return matches

print(listCompare(list1, list2))
```

That is, just use one index to loop through both lists, and create a variable called matches to count the number of matches you find.

Answer (score 0):

```
def listCompare(lst1, lst2):
    for i in lst1:
        for j in lst2:
            if i == j:
                return i
```

Your code compare each item in list1 to all item in list2.
You can use this code.

```
list1 = [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]
list2 = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]

def listCompare(lst1, lst2):
    i=0
    counter=0
    for j in lst1:
        if lst1[i]==lst2[i]:
            counter+=1
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
    return counter

print(listCompare(list1,list2))
```